# Norm in Sobolev Spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In an exercise, i would like to use the next afirmation.

Si $L=\delta_0$ y $v\in H^1_0$ entonces

$|<L,v>| =|v(0)| \le ||v||_\infty \le K_1 ||v||_{H^1} \le K_2 ||v||_{H^1_0}.$

But, i do not know if Its true that $||v||_\infty \le K_1 ||v||_{H^1}$. Is it a consequence of v is, in particular, continous ($H^1_0\subset C^0)$?
All of this in a domain $\Omega$ one dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that $H_0^1(\Omega) \subset C^0(\Omega)$ when $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$. This follows from the (second part of the) Sobolev embedding theorem as written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality). In fact, listed there is the stronger result that
$$H_0^1(\Omega) \subseteq C^{0,\frac12}(\Omega)$$
(the space of $1/2$-Holder continuous functions) with the embedding being continuous which gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it, but, why gives it the inequality? I don’t see it sorry.

Comment: The inequality comes from the fact the embedding is continuous. Continuity of the embedding exactly means that $\|v\|_{C^{0,1/2}} \leq K \|v\|_{H_0^1}$ for some $K$. The inequality you want then follows since $\|v\|_{\infty} \leq \|v\|_{C^{0,1/2}}$.

Comment: Okei! Thanks a lot!